# What options are available to use with the vscode:// url scheme?

Tags: url, visual-studio-code, network-protocols

In GitLab, when you click on the blue "Clone" button you will see several options:

- Clone with SSH
- Clone with HTTPS
- Open in your IDE

[image]

The "Open in your IDE" section shows the option "Visual Studio Code", which is a url of the following form:

```
vscode://vscode.git/clone?url=<url_encoded url pointing to the .git repository>
```

I am unable to find any documentation in the VSCode website. What other options are supported by VSCode apart from `vscode://vscode.git/clone?url=...` ? Where can I find more information about this?

> By "Options" I mean methods (`GET` / `POST`), servers (`vscode.git`), endpoints (`clone?...`) and parameters (`url=...`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `vscode://vscode.git/clone?url=...` is not supported by VS Code internally.
Instead, it uses a feature in VS Code that URLs can direct the handling of the URL to a registered extension, in this case *vscode.git*.
So, the `/clone?url=...` part is handled by the *vscode.git* extension and not internally by VS Code.

You can see this in the docs for vscode extensions API registerUriHandler: https://vscode-api.js.org/modules/vscode.window.html#registerUriHandler

Comment: I don't know the options available for other extensions, but apparently there is only one for the vscode.git extension: [clone](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/f88bce8fe6a6d2ccd27cbd64bb26853cd8779afa/extensions/git/src/protocolHandler.ts#L25).

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if we still have it in vscode docs, but going through the code I found that currently it supports adding `windowId=_blank` to help it open in new window analogous to `code -n <mypath>`.

e.g.
`<a href="vscode://file/<mypath>?windowId=_blank"> Open in Code</a>`

If we don't provide that it reuses the existing window, analogous to `code -r <mypath>`

Comment: That is still missing from the docs. I've submitted a comment to the docs page - it would be great if it were added.